# ng-click is not firing with factory class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory

I'm new in AngularJS. The following code is not executing after entering the username and password and clicking the login button. The login should execute the login method and populate person data binding object. Anybody knows why is not firing? Thanks.

Factory File

```
'use strict';

var usermodule = angular.module('retrieveBasicUserInfo', [])
.factory('basicUserInfo', function($http) {

    var credentials = {
        username: '',
        password: ''
    };
    var person = "";

    $http.defaults.useXDomain = true;

    var getBasicUserInfo = function (credentials) {
        var inputdata = { "Logon": credentials.username, "Pass": credentials.password};
        $http.post('http://localhost:23034/api/wmsusers/login',JSON.stringify(inputdata),
           {
               headers: {
                   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
                   'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' : 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT',
                   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                   'Accept': 'application/json'
               }
           }).success(function (inputdata) {
               person = inputdata[0];
           });
    };

    return {
        person: getBasicUserInfo
    };
});
```

JavaScript File

```
'use strict';

var usermodule = angular.module('wms', ['retrieveBasicUserInfo'])
    .controller('userAuthentication', ['basicUserInfo', function ($scope, basicUserInfo) {
        $scope.credentials = {
            username: '',
            password: ''
        };
        $scope.login = function (credentials) {
            console.log(credentials)
            $scope.person = basicUserInfo.getBasicUserInfo(credentials);
        }
    }]);
```

HTML File

```
<div data-ng-controller="userAuthentication">
<div class="login-panel">
    <p>Please complete the following form and click Login to continue:</p>
    <form name="loginForm" data-ng-submit="login(credentials)" novalidate>

        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username"
               data-ng-model="credentials.username">

        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password"
               data-ng-model="credentials.password">

        <button type="submit">Login</button>

    </form>
</div>
<br>
    <ul data-ng-model="$parent.person">
        <li>Name: {{person.Name}}</li>
        <li>Associate Id: {{person.Empid}}</li>
        <li>Access Level: {{person.Access}}</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please see here http://jsbin.com/vaweja/2/edit.

Your factory returns object with person property and in your controller you are trying to reach getBasicUserInfo so chnage person to getBasicUserInfo. And you missed $scope in your controller definition

change that

```
return {
        person: getBasicUserInfo
    };
```

to

```
return {
        getBasicUserInfo: getBasicUserInfo
    };
```

and

```
var usermodule = angular.module('wms', ['retrieveBasicUserInfo'])
//and you missed $scope in line bellow after bracket
    .controller('userAuthentication', ['$scope','basicUserInfo', function ($scope, basicUserInfo) {
        $scope.credentials = {
            username: '',
            password: ''
        };
        $scope.login = function (credentials) {
            console.log(credentials)
            $scope.person = basicUserInfo.getBasicUserInfo(credentials);
        }
    }])
```

;